# Android - Can draw Over Other App Requests to be set to Yes in Api 24

Tags: android

is it possible to get the CanDraw over other apps permission request to work in Api 24? It works in Api 23 for us but when trying on an api 24 device, it no longer works. Did something change with Api 24 that changes these requests?

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "it no longer works" means. In particular, explain what "it" is and what the exact symptoms are that you describe as "no longer works". You might consider including a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They (Android team) changed the severity of this Permission, and now users have to go to the settings and enable it manually, the more you can do is open up the settings page for them, but, they need to toggle the switch so that your app can get permission to do so.